# Time format in datetime picker

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to pick date and time using a jquery datetimepicker.I tried the following code for picking date and time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#datepickerImage").datetimepicker({
          timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
       });
     });
</script>
```

But I got 24hr clock and also not shown am/pm. Please help me

Comment: Try timeFormat: "hh:MM tt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
timeFormat: "HH:mm tt",
```

Or you can use

```
timeFormat: "GG:mm tt",
```

Or you can try like

```
ampm: true,
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
```

Comment: no it shows H. I use <script src="~/Script/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script> to add time with datepicker